# Sending data in real-time from Python to .NET Core

Tags: python, c#, websocket, signalr

So we have a .NET core application running on a server with SignalR,
basically this application moves an object on the screen under realtime,
The SignalR application have a function

```
    public async Task SendMessage(string x, string y)
    {
        await Clients.All.ReceiveMessage(x, y);
    }
```

Within the application I can send the new x and y and the object is moved,
but the problem is that we get the data (x, y) from a Python application
and we want to send it to the .NET Core application in real-time.

What is the best solution for this problem and also is sending and receiving the data with HTTP GET a good solution?
something like:

```
    [Route("Send/{x}/{y}")]
    public async Task Send(string x, string y)
    {
        await _strongTagHubContext.Clients.All.ReceiveMessage(x,y);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - I almost understood your question but not quite. Is your python app a web app (e.g. flask)? Does the data just go `python -> .net` or do you need two way communication? If it's one way then I would send the data in the body of a `POST` request, as this is usually used when sending data to a server, a `GET` is for retrieving data. If you need real time between the apps you need to set up websockets (e.g. flask-socketio) or there may be a signalR client for python too.

Comment: Hi @elembie and thanks for the comment, our Python is a Console application that prints the postilions (x, y) each second and the data  goes one way Python-->.NET core. In the Python we used a third party library to communicate with SignalR  but It didn't quite work, do you think we are missing something like allowing CORS, and do you think that POST request will be a good solution with x , y updating each second?

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have the solution to your inquiry:\

To communicate between 2 softwares that use are "differently coded"(like **DOTNET** and **PYTHON**), the best way is to simply connect using **TCP**.

Connect the TCP once both softwares are loaded and ready, and keep it alive to communicate. As simple as that

I hope that resolved your problem, let me know if that's not the case :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there other ways?, and what do you think about the HTTP GET solution?

Comment: Well, HTTP GET isn't a bad idea, but it might make a slight delay, so doing realtime using HTTP REQUESTS might be a little complicated.